# arcpy clean up of variables in cursors vs. loops

Tags: arcpy

I'm new to Python & ArcPy. I'm used to cleaning up temporary variables used in loops after completing the loop to keep my workspace clean. I think I read that variables created in cursors are temporary and deleted once the cursor completes? In the code sample below, what (if any) should my clean up steps be?

```
counts = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (outFeatureClass.shp, "Zone_ID") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if not row[0] in counts.keys():
            counts[row[0]] = 1
        else:
            counts[row[0]] += 1
# del row?? cursor??

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(outFeatureClass.shp, ["Zone_ID", "N_1"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        zone = row[0]
        if zone in counts:
            row[1] = counts[zone]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
# del row?? zone?? cursor??

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(outFeatureClass4.shp, ["Zone_ID", "N_1"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        zone = row[0]
        if zone in counts:
            row[1] = counts[zone]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
# del row?? zone?? cursor??
```

Comment: thanks for the dup link @PolyGeo; it answers my question